# Псевдоэлемент first-line

Tags: css

Почему-то не работает этот псевдоэлемент в медиа запросах, в десктопе все норм

```css
.textBlock:first-line {
  text-transform: upperCase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
.textBlock:first-line {
  text-transform: upperCase;
  font-size: 15px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="textBlock"> some text <br> some text some text some text some text some text some text <br> some text some text some text some text </div>
```

---

Сколько раз мне скидывать одно и тоже, чтобы вы поняли?
Я скидываю то, как у меня написан медиа запрос.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .textBlock:first-line {
    color: green;
    text-transform: lowercase;
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что элемент не работает именно в медиа запросах?

Comment: потому что я добавил его в медиа запрос и все сломалось, если же убираю его. т.к он есть в основных стилях. то все равно не работает, хотя в коде элемента отображается

Comment: добавь необходимую разметку и стили в сам вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: А в медиа-запросе как прописывали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, не знаю, прописываю, скажем, так:

```css
.textBlock:first-line {
  text-transform: upperCase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .textBlock:first-line {
    color: green;
    text-transform: lowercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textBlock"> some text <br> some text some text some text some text some text some text <br> some text some text some text some text </div>
```

И отлично всё работает при развороте на весь экран. То есть медиа-запрос отрабатывает. Покажите КАК у вас прописан медиа-запрос?

Comment: Вы в курсе, что device-width определяется не как ширина окна браузера, например, а как ширина окна устройства? Например, если я сверну (уменьшу размер окна браузера), монитор как был шириной 1920 пикселей, так и останется. И ваше условие не сработает на моём мониторе никогда.

Comment: Хорошо, у меня есть несколько device-width и я в каждый из них написал свой код, но он все равно не отрабатывает

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, а вы эти условия с device-width, которых у вас несколько, каждое проверяете на разных устройствах у которых действительно разные разрешения экранов?

Comment: типа, неважно как я прописываю max-device-width or max-width

Comment: Проверяю я через код элемента, меняя устройства там

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста https://habr.com/ru/company/paysto/blog/254871/ вы не можете программно указать device-width как вам хочется. Такая ширина вычисляется как ширина устройства, например, монитора. Если ставите условие как `max-device-width: 450px` то и проверять, работает ли условие надо на мобильном устройстве, у которого ширина экрана меньше 450 пикселей. На мониторе, ширина которого, к примеру, 1920 пикселей - условие не сработает никогда.